# Implementing a SAML assertion flow with Spring Oauth2

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-saml

I need to implement a SAML assertion flow using Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server.  I'm struggling with how to tie these two projects up. 
 I've tried importing the SAML securityContext into my OAuth project as well, however it seems that the SAML flow will always take precedence.  Is there a way to do this where it would look at the grant_type to determine if it should use the saml flow.

Also, when it does process the saml assertion, would that tie into the ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter, or would I have to register a custom token granter with something like this?

```
 With OAuth2, we have a way of registering different TokenGranters through something like this:

 List<TokenGranter> tokenGranters = new ArrayList<TokenGranter>();
    tokenGranters.add( endpoints.getTokenGranter());
    tokenGranters.add(new SamlTokenGranter(authenticationManager,tks,cds,endpoints.getOAuth2RequestFactory()));
    CompositeTokenGranter ctg = new CompositeTokenGranter(tokenGranters);
    endpoints.tokenGranter(ctg);
```

thanks ahead of time for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

You might need to register a custom `TokenGranter`. The `CompositeTokenGranter` (the default) can handle multiple grant types by doing what you suggest (comparing the incoming requested `grant_type` to the one supported by each granter). If you are using Spring SAML as a service provider to check the assertion, then I guess you also need to set that up as a separate security filter on the /token endpoint (with a very specific request matcher so it only intercepts SAML grants).

Comment: P.S. I'd be quite interested to see this working, so please persevere and maybe we can share the result through the framework(s).